# Bootstrap change order of rows/columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple grid, like so (this is what I want it to look on x-small and small displays):

```
BBBBBBBB
AAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAA  
AAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAA
...
CCCCCCCC
CCCCCCCC
```

This is what I want for medium and large displays:

```
AAAAAAAA | BBBB
AAAAAAAA | CCCC
AAAAAAAA | CCCC  
AAAAAAAA |
...
```

This is, what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/hpf597hq/9/

Resize the result-window to see what's going wrong there

It looks as if I'm fairly close to what I want to accomplish, but I actually have no clue, how to fix that gap between the red and the blue div.

Is that even possible?

Regards,
Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the classes `col-md-push-8 and col-md-pull-4` and have targeted the divs for larger device only using media queries. I have floated the first and last div to the right which gave the intended result.

```
@media (min-width:992px) {
   .col-md-4 {
       float:right;
   }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/hpf597hq/10/)

Comment: Thank you, should have thought of that myself. Here's the solution:  http://jsfiddle.net/hpf597hq/14/